# Flipping a gui Component in the x-z plane

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I would like to know  the respective graphics transformations ..in creating a flipping effect of  a ui component about the x-z plane. It needs to be done only using 2d since the swing toolkit only supports 2d affine transformations.

http://www.verysimple.com/flex/flipcard/ .... is an example of the effect to be achieved .

Comment: Your question isn't very clear (at least to me).  Why would you expect to be able to do a 3D transformation (which is what your use of the z coordinate implies) using only 2D transformations?

Could you give a concrete example of how the transformation should work?

Comment: Also, x-z plane isn't very clear. They tend to be named differently here and there. Which plane is what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a true 3-D flipping but the effect looks very similar if you just do 2-D scaling like this,

1. Render the front image.
2. Scale X from 1 to 0, anchored at the middle.
3. Render the back image.
4. Scale X from 0 to 1, anchored at the middle.

To simulate a constant angular speed, the scaling factor can be calculated like this,

```
double scale = Math.cos(i*Math.PI/(2.0*steps));
```

The `i` is step number and `steps` is the total number of steps need to simulate a 90 degree rotation.

You can also introduce some shear transformation to simulate the perspective of a true 3-D rotation but the effect is not that noticeable for a fast flipping.